# How to share static files among developers

Tags: django, git

I've been developing with Django for a while now and up until now it's always been by myself. I'm working with a person now and I've run into an issue with static files.

My set up is like this:

```
local -- version control on GitHub
      \- heroku 
           |
          s3 for static files
```

If I was pushing to production I'd run `git push heroku master` followed by `python manage.py collectstatic` which would then push it to S3. I'd open it on Heroku and both would work hand in hand.

The front end dev came along and I got the project running on his computer. We cloned the repo from GitHub, ran the server and there were no static files which makes sense since there are no static files in the repo.

In the end I had to compress my static files and send them to him over Slack while I thought about it. If he updates something and I want to see it he'd have to get it to me too through something similar. It seems at the minute the only way to get around this is to add the static files to git but this feels wrong or something. Any experiences with this?

Comment: Maybe `rsync` your directory with his?

Comment: Your static files should be tracked inside your git repository as well

Comment: Oh... well. Shows over, folks.

Comment: If you feel your static files don't fit your code repository, just put 'em to the another repository. But surely you'll need a tool to sync them (and a tool to not forget about it).